# VBA 'User Defined Type Not Defined' Compile Error with Outlook

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I have a big Excel file that sends, with a command button, e-mails to Managers at work, and then they can press the button and it sends the files to Managers below them.

Since every manager has her/his own version of `MS Office`, I have a sub that checks which version (s)he has on her/his computer and marks `V` in `References`.

When I save the file, I save it in a status that `Outlook Object Library` is not marked with `V`, and I have code that someone else built. The code runs through 3 subs. The first sub has a `msgbox` that when you answer on it, <kbd>Yes</kbd> , it sends you to next sub.

```
Public Sub before_send_mail()

    answer = MsgBox("Send Email?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Empty Sheet")

    If answer = vbYes Then
        Call excel_ver
        Call sendMail
        Call remove_ref
    Else
     'do nothing
    End If

End Sub
```

Then, I have the "references picker by office version" that checks which version there is installed on the computer and marks `V` automatically in `Tools---->References` in `Outlook` object. That part seems to work well too.

```
Sub excel_ver()

    On Error Resume Next
    ver = Application.Version

    If ver = 16 Then
        tmp_name = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office16\MSOUTL.OLB"
        Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.References.AddFromFile tmp_name
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If ver = 15 Then
        tmp_name = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\MSOUTL.OLB"
        Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.References.AddFromFile tmp_name
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If ver = 14 Then
        tmp_name = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\MSOUTL.OLB"
        Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.References.AddFromFile tmp_name
        Exit Sub
    End If

End Sub
```

And then we get to the problem. When I get to sub `sendMail` it gives me an error on the line `Dim applOL As Outlook.Application`

```
Public Sub sendMail()

    Call ini_set

    If mail_msg.Cells(200, 200) = 1 Then

        lr = main_dist.Cells(main_dist.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        On Error Resume Next

        For i = 2 To lr

            Application.DisplayAlerts = False

            Dim applOL As Outlook.Application 'Here is the error ---- that line
            Dim miOL As Outlook.MailItem
            Dim recptOL As Outlook.Recipient

            mail_msg.Visible = True

            mailSub = mail_msg.Range("B1")
            mailBody = mail_msg.Range("B2")

            mail_msg.Visible = False

            Set applOL = New Outlook.Application
            Set miOL = applOL.CreateItem(olMailItem)
            Set recptOL = miOL.Recipients.Add(main_dist.Cells(i, 5))
            recptOL.Type = olTo

            tempPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & main_dist.Cells(i, 4) & ".xlsm"

            With miOL
                .Subject = mailSub
                .Body = mailBody
                .Attachments.Add tempPath
                .send     
            End With

            Set applOL = Nothing
            Set miOL = Nothing
            Set recptOL = Nothing

            Application.DisplayAlerts = True

        Next i
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Make an early binding to "Office14" Outlook (the lowest denominator). If user has higher version, VBA will fix the reference automatically.

Comment: `marks V in references` ?  `popes me an error` ??

Comment: Or if performance not horrendously impacted consider late binding? Removes the need for a lot of the code.

Comment: @ashleedawg I have made a stab at correcting this in the hope the OP will come back and further improve.

Comment: And the actual question seems to be missing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should run with no reference required:

```
Public Sub sendMail()

    Dim applOL As Object, miOL As Object, recptOL As Object
    Dim i As Long

    ini_set

    If mail_msg.Cells(200, 200) = 1 Then

        Set applOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

        For i = 2 To main_dist.Cells(main_dist.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

            Set miOL = applOL.CreateItem(0)  'olMailItem=0
            Set recptOL = miOL.Recipients.Add(main_dist.Cells(i, 5))
            recptOL.Type = 1  ' olTo=1

            With miOL
                .Subject = mail_msg.Range("B1")
                .Body = mail_msg.Range("B2")
                .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & _
                                 main_dist.Cells(i, 4) & ".xlsm"
                .send
            End With
        Next i
        Set applOL = Nothing
   End If
End Sub
```

EDIT: in the code above I removed some of your "single-use" variables, but that's just my preference...

Answer (score 3):

During pre-compile process `Outlook.Application` is not valid as it is not set in `Tools\References...`. If you want to keep your code working you need to run `ini_set` first and before `sendMail` is even compiled. Try to add new subroutine to call both in a sequence:

```
Sub MainSub()
    call ini_set
    call sendMail
End Sub
```

To make it clear- remove `Call ini_set` from your `sendMail` and each time you have to call both do it from separate subroutine.

**Important!** With this solution you could keep `outlook appilcation constants` (like `olMailItem`) which is not possible when you switch to `Late binding solution`.